# When changing a string inside of a 2d array, it doesn't change

Tags: c++

Sorry if it is a bit vague, but I am making a tic-tac-toe game for practice, and the computer is changing squares on the board randomly, but when it reaches a certain if loop, it doesn't change the square.

The array looks like this for context:

```
{ a , "| ", a , "| ", a ,
 "- ", "+ ", "- ", "+ ", "- ",
  a , "| ", a , "| ", a ,
 "- ", "+ ", "- ", "+ ", "- ",
  a , "| ", a , "| ", a };
```

It's inside a while loop where if the randomly generated 2 points (xx, xy) inside the array as `Array[xx][xy]` and it lands on one of the `|` or `+` or `-` strings ( which are there to make it look nicer ), it restarts the loop until it gets an actual spot. ( a ).

This is the loop:

```cpp
bool done = false;
while(!done) {
    xx = rand() % rows;
    xy = rand() % elements;
    
    if (Board[xx][xy] == "| " ||
        Board[xx][xy] == "0 " ||
        Board[xx][xy] == "+ " ||
        Board[xx][xy] == "- ") {
         continue;
     } else {
         Board[xx][xy] == "X ";
         done = true;
     }
```

When it retries and retries and gets to the `else {}`, it exits the loop using `done = true;` but it does not change `Board[xx][xy]` to X.

I am kinda confused as no errors show up in the debugger.

Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment.

Comment: Board[xx][xy] == "X " ...

Answer (score 1):

> it does not change Board[xx][xy] to X

This is because `Board[xx][xy] == "X ";` is a comparison. That whole statement will return a bool, but you're not assigning anything anywhere.

What you're looking for is `Board[xx][xy] = "X ";`, with just one `=` sign.